# Is there a way to execute XHR Requests via VS Code Extension?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am building a VS Code extension and in that, I need to execute an XHR Request to my server to fetch some data.

I tried using this in my code :

```
    function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage(this.responseText);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2", true);
    xhttp.send();
  }
```

but it is showing an error :

[image]

Any idea, how can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

`XMLHttpRequest` and `fetch` are only available in the browser. vsCode is node.js based. Use `Axios` instead. [How can I make a POST request in a VSCode extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65146333/how-can-i-make-a-post-request-in-a-vscode-extension)